# Boxfuse + Jhipster project

Tags: jhipster, cloudcaptain

Can anyone give some pointer on how to deploy a jhipster created spring boot app on aws using boxfuse.
I have tried it,but couldn't do it successfully.

NOTE - in boxfuse documentation

Database - > Character encoding

PostgreSQL  - >  UTF8

MySQL   ->     utf8mb4

So while using MySQL,you can change varchar(255) to varchar(191) to avoid following error:

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be caused by two issues:

1. A defect in the MySQL support on the JHipster side: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3996
2. Lack of JHipster support on the Boxfuse side

Starting today, Boxfuse now has [first-class support for JHipster](https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/jhipster) and everything should work as expected.